# Print data from an ArrayList Object which is inside another ArrayList

Tags: android, json, arraylist

The title might seem familiar, but the problem isn't. I've referred many posts/articles, and finally posting my question.

I receive data from JSON [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008494/parse-json-array-inside-json-array-with-android), and from "Home" fragment I save data to a getter setter class "StudentDetails", and then access it from another fragment "StudentFees".

PROBLEM: The last object of the inner array gets printed the number of times the outer array runs.

Below is my "Home" Fragment

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

private ArrayList<StudentDetails> arrayListHome;
private ArrayList<StudentDetails> arrayListTransaction;

private StudentDetails studentDetails;
private StudentDetails studentDetails1;

JSONArray jsonArrayHome = jsonObjectHome.getJSONArray("responseData");
arrayListHome = new ArrayList<StudentDetails>();

//  First array

    for (int a = 0; a < jsonArrayHome.length(); a++) {

    JSONObject jsonObjectStudent = jsonArrayHome.getJSONObject(a);
    studentDetails = new StudentDetails();

//      Set student ID
    if (!jsonObjectStudent.isNull("student_id")) {
        studentDetails.setStudentId(jsonObjectStudent.getString("student_id"));
    }

    JSONArray jsonArrayTransaction = jsonObjectStudent.getJSONArray("transaction");
    arrayListTransaction = new ArrayList<StudentDetails>();

//      Second array
    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayTransaction.length(); j++) {

        JSONObject jsonObjectTransaction = jsonArrayTransaction.getJSONObject(j);
        studentDetails1 = new StudentDetails();

//          Set receipt no.
        if (!jsonObjectTransaction.isNull("receipt_no")) {
            studentDetails1.setReceiptNo(jsonObjectTransaction.getString("receipt_no"));
        }

        arrayListTransaction.add(studentDetails1);
        Log.d("At Home receipt no.", arrayListTransaction.get(j).getReceiptNo()+"");
    }
    studentDetails1.setArrayListTransaction(arrayListTransaction);
    arrayListHome.add(studentDetails);
    Log.d("At Home student id", arrayListHome.get(a).getStudentId());
}
studentDetails.setArray(arrayListHome);
}
```

Below is "StudentDetails" class

```
public class StudentDetails {

private static ArrayList<StudentDetails> arrayListDetails = null;
private static ArrayList<StudentDetails> arrayListTransaction = null;

private String studentId = null;
private String receiptNo = null;

public void setArray(ArrayList<StudentDetails> arrayList) {
    arrayListDetails = arrayList;
}

public ArrayList<StudentDetails> getArray() {
    return arrayListDetails;
}

public void setStudentId(String sId) {
    studentId = sId;
}

public String getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}

public void setArrayTransaction(ArrayList<StudentDetails> transaction){
    arrayListTransaction = transaction;
}

public ArrayList<StudentDetails> getArrayTransaction (){
    return arrayListTransaction;
}

public void setReceiptNo(String sReceiptNo) {
    receiptNo = sReceiptNo;
}

public String getReceiptNo() {
    return receiptNo;
}
```

Below is "StudentFees" Fragment

```
public class StudentFees extends Fragment {

StudentDetails studentDetails = new StudentDetails();
final ArrayList<StudentDetails> arrayListFees = studentDetails.getArray();

//  First Array
for (int k = 0; k < arrayListFees.size(); k++) {

    final TextView textViewId = new TextView(getActivity());
    textViewId.setId(View.generateViewId());

    Log.d("At Fees student id", arrayListFees.get(k).getStudentId());
    textViewId.setText(arrayListFees.get(k).getStudentId());

    StudentDetails studentDetails1 =  new StudentDetails();
    ArrayList<StudentDetails> arrayListTransaction = studentDetails1.getArrayTransaction(); 

    TextView textViewReceiptNo = null;

    //  Second Array
    for (int l = 0; l < arrayListTransaction.size() /*studentDetails.getArrayTransaction().size()*/; l++) {

        // StudentDetails studentDetails1 = new StudentDetails();
        // ArrayList<StudentDetails> arrayListTransaction = studentDetails1.getArrayTransaction();

        textViewReceiptNo = new TextView(getActivity());
        textViewReceiptNo.setId(View.generateViewId());

        Log.d("At Fees receipt no.", arrayListTransaction.get(l).getReceiptNo());
        textViewReceiptNo.setText(arrayListTransaction.get(l).getReceiptNo());
    }
}
}
```

Data insertion log @ Home fragment:

```
D/At Home receipt no.: R/100/2017/04/2449
D/At Home receipt no.: R/100/2017/04/2450
D/At Home student id: 201510353
D/At Home receipt no.: R/100/2017/04/2536
D/At Home receipt no.: R/100/2017/04/2537
D/At Home receipt no.: R/100/2017/11/3024
D/At Home student id: 201610113
```

Data retrieval @ StudentFees fragment

```
D/At Fees student id: 201510353
D/At Fees receipt no.: R/100/2017/04/2536
D/At Fees receipt no.: R/100/2017/04/2537
D/At Fees receipt no.: R/100/2017/11/3024
D/At Fees student id: 201610113
D/At Fees receipt no.: R/100/2017/04/2536
D/At Fees receipt no.: R/100/2017/04/2537
D/At Fees receipt no.: R/100/2017/11/3024
```

Desired output is smilar to data inserted.

NOTE: I've [referred this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843506/why-does-my-arraylist-contain-n-copies-of-the-last-item-added-to-the-list), but still used "static" ArrayList variable on purpose, as I need to access this ArrayList from other fragments.

JSON Data:

```
{
"responseCode": "200",
"status": "true",
"responseData": [{
    "student_id": "201510353",
    "transaction": [{
        "receipt_no": "R\/100\/2017\/04\/2449"
    }, {
        "receipt_no": "R\/100\/2017\/04\/2450"
    }]
}, {
    "student_id": "201610113",
    "transaction": [{
        "receipt_no": "R\/100\/2017\/04\/2536"
    }, {
        "receipt_no": "R\/100\/2017\/04\/2537"
    }, {
        "receipt_no": "R\/100\/2017\/11\/3024"
    }]
}]
}
```

Comment: add your json response with your question.

Comment: @Guruji, please check the JSON data